# My image isn't converting to grayscale while using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I've tried converting my image to grayscale using multiple methods, but my image won't convert

I tried:

```
image = cv2.imread(r"path\shoe.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray image',gray)
```

But the image stays the same

Comment: Use only one method. Either 0 in the imread or BGR2GRAY, not both. Does that help. Perhaps your image is already grayscale?

Comment: your image variable is an grayscale. the flag "0" is for reading in grayscale mode. u can read in BGR mode using cv2.imread("pathOfImage") and convert after

Comment: I removed the 0 in imread but it's still the same thing, here's a link to the picture https://ibb.co/4Kf3TqL @fmw42

Comment: I see no link to the picture!

Comment: Did you import cv2?

Comment: @fmw42 yes, I did import cv2, I've attached the link

Comment: The reason is that you are showing `image` instead of `gray`. Also, add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

you can read images as grayscale directly

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_path=r'your path'
img=cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV with your image on my Mac desktop along with the script. Two issues. 1) Your image is webp not png (at least what I can download from your link).  2) You need to add cv2.waitKey(0).

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("shoe.webp")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray image',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Oh, so the image must be in the wrong format, I used the snipping tool to get the image. Do all images have to be PNG for it to be converted to grayscale image?
Also, I added the cv2.waitKey(0) just forgot to put it in the code snippet

Comment: No all images do not have to be PNG.  Any image that is compatible with your Python/OpenCV.  Perhaps you do not have a version that includes WEBP library.  If you computer can handle webp, then convert it from webp to png and try the png instead in your code.

Comment: When posting code, be sure you have listed a fully reproducible set of code. Don't leave out parts.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what format the image is in because it doesn't convert to grayscale for me. I even tried using snipping tool and snipped the picture and ensured it was in PNG but it still didn't convert to grayscale

Comment: the images are taken from here: https://www.nike.com/ie/t/air-force-1-07-shoes-GjGXSP/CW2288-111?cp=35596902505_search_%7c%7c10564800177%7c103186519374%7c%7cc%7cEN%7ccssproducts%7c454138247005&ds_rl=1252249&gclid=Cj0KCQiA_bieBhDSARIsADU4zLceuuR6aeCT5fP3dQDMIHgqEha3OayYqOBOEIJHNvv0Xvs1gwiPbeIaAm_kEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds.
But for some reason, it just won't convert.

Comment: The file I downloaded from that web site is a JPG. Try changing the file format to JPG in the file and in your python command

Comment: I tried changing it to jpg, but it didn't work
Is it definitely working for you? I was playing around with the grayscale conversion and it seems to only work when the picture has other colours inside it too for example black. If it's pure white like the picture it doesn't seem to convert

Comment: As I showed above, it converts fine for me (your webp version). It also works from the jpg file I downloaded from the web site link:  air-force-1-07-shoes-GjGXSP.png.jpeg

Comment: Is your path correct?

Comment: try double \\ in place of \ and without the r prefix.  also try forward slashes / with and without the r prefix

Comment: Are you sure that the code you have written in the answer works for you? The conversion will surely work, but you are visualizing `image` instead of `gray`. So with this code, how can we see the grayscale image?

Comment: @fmw42 the path is fine, I even tried replacing the \ with /, I'm still getting the same issue.
The issue doesn't occur with images that have more colour

Comment: Is the path is sub folder `path\shoe.png`? should be `shoe.png`.

Comment: The path should be where ever you have the image located.

Comment: @sgarizvi. You are correct. My typo. But it does work if I imshow("gray", gray) and the result is just grayscale, not color. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: So what was the solution?